# Can you avoid military service in Ukraine when you are studying at an university?

Tags: military, ukraine

Is it possible to not go to the army in Ukraine due to the person being engaged in studying at a university? I mean not going to the army at all and studying at the university until you are 27 years old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

According to Ukraine Law #2232, a.17-18 ([Ukrainian version](http://zakon3.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/2232-12/page2),[English version(paywalled)](http://cis-legislation.com/document.fwx?rgn=16029)), if one pursues a scientific career (i.e. aims to achieve a doctorate) - university students get their draft postponed for the whole time of education, and doctorate holders are exempt from draft for as long as they work in their field of expertise. Also, during education it is possible to extend the postponement up to 10 years: 4 years of bachelor's course + 2 years master's + up 3 years of grad school, and one year given to write a thesis allow someone who applied to university at 17 to leave at 28, so one can achieve the goal of dodging draft without actually finishing grad school, I guess.

Comment: Hmm. But now bachelor degree takes up only 4 years...

Comment: @trafalgarLaww well, you still get just enough time - it actually adeed up to 11 years, I just forgot to add the 1 year thesis there. I'll edit those 4 years in.